# Oracle security policy

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

How to Create a FUNCTION that restrict users to seeing only employees with a salary of 1,500 or less ?? As an example: if i enter

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM employee;

EMPNUMB EMPNAME STARTDATE ENDDATE  SALARY  EMPCITY   DESCRIPTION
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
01      Jason Martin 25-JUL-96 25-JUL-06 1234.56 Geelong   Programmer
08      James Cat 17-SEP-96 15-APR-02 1232.78 Melbourne Tester
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want a function, you want a view:

```
create view employee_view as
select * from employee where salary <= 1500;
```

Then only grant users access to the view, not the table.  If necessary you can rename so that the view is called `employee` and the base table is called `employee_table` or whatever.

Alternatively, noting the title of your question, you could look at [Virtual Private Database (VPD)](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28531/vpd.htm#CIHCBCFJ) aka "Fine-grained access control".  But that sounds like overkill for your stated requirement, and is only available in Enterprise Edition.